# Localizing with different element count

Tags: ios, nslocalizedstring, localizable.strings

I'd like to give my users a warm welcome, when they are opening my application. So I want to have different sentences to show them randomly. The count of messages differs in each language.

What is the preferred way to solve this problem?

My ideas:

1. Save the count also in the strings file ->  Don't like this idea, because this must be maintained
   `"welcomeCount" = "5";`
   `"welcomeN" = "Hi....";`
2. Seperating the messages -> Don't like this idea, because you have to mind this
   `"welcomeMessages" = "Hey there...|MessageN";`

Anyone out there with an idea to solve this issue in a elegant manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the welcome messages in localized property lists.

- In Xcode, go to File -> New -> File ...
- Choose the Resource -> Property List template and for example "Welcome.plist" as file name.
- Select Welcome.plist in Xcode and change the type of the root object from *Dictionary* to *Array*.
- Select Welcome.plist, to go the File Inspector and click on "Make Localized ...". Then select the localizations that you want for the Welcome.plist., for example English and German.
- Now you have a Welcome.plist for each language which you can edit separately.
- To add strings, click on the "+" symbol in the property list.

In your program, you can load the list easily with

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Welcome" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *messages = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

This loads the "right" properly list, depending on the user's language, into the array `messages`. You can choose a random message with

```
int idx = arc4random_uniform([messages count]);
NSString *msg = [messages objectAtIndex:idx];
```

Answer (score 0):

To minimize maintenance, you can use a binary search to find out how many variations are available. Say you have the following in your `Localizable.strings`:

```
"Welcome_0" = "Hello";
"Welcome_1" = "Hi";
"Welcome_2" = "What up";
"Welcome_3" = "Howdy";
```

You can find the count using:

```
int lower = 0, upper = 10;
while (lower < upper - 1) {
    int mid = (lower + upper) / 2;
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome_%i", mid];
    BOOL isAvailable = ![key isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(key, @"")];
    if (isAvailable) lower = mid;
    else upper = mid;
}
```

Finally select you random message using:

```
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome_%i", rand() % upper];
NSString *welcome = NSLocalizedString(key, @"");
```

Comment: Sure,... I am hoping, that there is something like `"welcomeMessages" = ["a", "b", "n"];`

Getting the value(s) via NSLocalizedString (randomly) or NSLocalizedArray...

So far, thx for your answer. :)